# How to get wlan0 rate from cli

Tags: network-monitoring, command-line

question is in title, best would be from some file in /sys instead of parsing output of iwlist ?

I need this number from output of iwconfig "Bit Rate=**54** Mb/s".

Thanks

Comment: after searching more about this, i found out that even iwconfig is calling syscall ioctl(d, SIOCGIWRATE, ...). So, parsing output of iwconfig or customizing source code of iwconfig would be optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would do it.

```
iwconfig wlan0 | grep Bit | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/Rate=//'
```

This will return the data rate.

Comment: yes, im doing with this 
iwconfig wlan0 | grep Rate | cut -f 2 -d "=" | cut -f 1 -d " "
now, but, still, it will be faster to read it from file ( if it is stored somewhere in decimal )then running iwconfig, grep,awk and sed ( or in my case 2x cut )

Comment: I don't think there is another way of getting the bit rate value. 
You can probably, without any problems run the command over 100 times per second if you want to.